# what does it mean to subtract a character from a character

Tags: ascii

i am following an example [enter link description here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706) but i have one small confusion.  What does the following line mean?

```
int charPos = word.charAt(0) - 'a';
```

What does it actually mean to subtract a letter from a char ?
i am wondering if this is how you get the position of the char in the alphabet.

Comment: since you downvoted, could you tell me what board i can go to to get help with this coding question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you the position relative to the `a` char in the character (ASCII) table. If the input char is lowercase, this is also the position in the alphabet (zero index based).

Example:

`'Z' - 'a'` gives you `90 - 97 = -7`

`'b' - 'a'` gives you `98 - 97 = 1`

Answer (score 3):

'a' in the ascii table is 97, 'b' - 'a' would be equivalent to 98 - 97, resulting in 1, which is b's position in the alphabetical array (a being 0)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in theory but the reference to ASCII is just plain wrong.

In Java, `charAt` returns a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit. [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) encodes some Unicode codepoints in one code unit; some in two. If your data is in the ranges of codepoints that UTF-16 encodes in one code unit then subtraction is the "distance" between those codepoints. If the codepoints are in a range where there is some "meaningful" order then the distance makes sense.

For example, the [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) lowercase letters are in the order of the English alphabet and UTF-16 encodes them in one code unit. Distance would be along a "alphabet line" instead of a "number line." This works for English and some other alphabets but not for many others.

Further, subtraction from 'a' would map 'a' to 0, 'b' to 1, 'z' to 25, …. What's after 'z'? Well, maybe you shouldn't apply this code to such data. In fact, even if your text is only English words in lowercase, the algorithm wouldn't be able to handle the English words "naïve" or "resumé."

BTW—There are about 120,000 "letters" in Unicode from dozens of writing systems (scripts) used by many dozens of languages, each with what some learned body designates as an alphabet.

Comment: @adjan Only in the sense that Unicode has all the characters that ASCII does. When you are working with text, text exists in exactly one encoding and, in this case, ASCII isn't it. Users of `charAt` should understand which values it can return and their meaning.